# Insert table1 row values into table2 columns in SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm about to write a query and was thinking if anybody can help me out.Please have a look at attached image and at the same time let me tell you brief overview of my requirement.

**Table1 Screenshot**
[image]

**Table2 Screenshot**
[image]

In **Table1**, we can have maximum 4 and minimum 2 records per user per day. If a user have 4 records then FirstRecord of the day In **Table1** will go to **Time1** column in **Table2**, second will go to **Time2** and so on. If a user have 2 records per day than First record of the day will go to **Time2** column in **Table2** and second record will go to **Time3** column. For references, Tables screen shots are attached.

Any useful link or query would be appreciated

Comment: Share some sample data and your effort you made to achieve this.

Comment: You can see the sample data by clicking on the screen shots link.

Answer (score 0):

Use ROW_NUMBER() and partition by `UserID` and order by `TransactionDate` to generate numbers 1-4 or 1-2 for each user.

Then insert into Table 2 with a CASE expression for each of the four time columns.

The CASE will check a subquery to get the MAX(RowNumber) for that User, and then SELECT the appropriate row from Table 1 based on the logic you gave for the two cases.